# Event listener target is null after delay with set time out

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am making a browser extension and I want to modify some things on the page but I run into this problem.

Then event listener gets triggered 'plug-stats' is not yet created by script on the page I can't control and gives me undefined so I tried to read it a little bit later but then I run into a problem.

First console log will give me a target as expected but I can't do anything with it yet because 'plug-stats' were not yet created.
Second console log gives me null.

Why is this happening and any ideas on how can I fix it?

```
let perk = document.querySelectorAll('.ItemPerksList-m_plug-O8be3')
perk.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', add_perk_description);
});

function add_perk_description(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(event.currentTarget)
        let html = event.currentTarget.getElementsByClassName('plug-stats')[0]
    }, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, the documentation for `Event.currentTarget` actually mentions this:

> The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the event is
> being handled. If you console.log() the event object, storing it in a
> variable, and then look for the currentTarget key in the console, its
> value will be null.

The *while the event is being handled* part should essentially be read as *synchronously within the event hanlder function* as I understand.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

You could still keep a reference to the current target for instance by synchronously assigning it to a local variable - and then referring to this local variable in the `setTimeout()` callback function.

```
function add_perk_description(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    let currentTarget = event.currentTarget
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(currentTarget)
        let html = currentTarget.getElementsByClassName('plug-stats')[0]
        }
    }, 1)
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer works flawlessly i actually tied setting even as a variable and it didn't work now I understand why it was because I tried to change the name variable instead of making a new variable
(this "let newEvent = event" instead of "let newEvent = event.target")

Comment: You set the local variable `currentTarget` at the time the value of `event.currentTarget` is null. So, this function will never work. You should move the `let currentTarget = event.currentTarget` part inside the setTimeout function.

Comment: The `null` note was removed from the docs in a recent update... thanks for including a copy here.

Answer (score 0):

try this code pass the event as parameter to settimeout-

```
function add_perk_description(e){
    console.log(e.target)
    setTimeout(function(event) {
        console.log(event.target)
    },500, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second Console gives you a **NULL** because event.currentTarget return a valid value at the time of being handled but callback runs after a 1 milliSeconds that's the reason it shows Null.

**Try out this**

```
let perk = document.querySelectorAll('.ItemPerksList-m_plug-O8be3')
    perk.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', e => {
            add_perk_description(e)
        })
    })

    function add_perk_description(event){
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
        **let {currentTarget}=e;**
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(currentTarget);
            let html = e.currentTarget.getElementsByClassName('plug-stats')[0]
            }
        }, 1)
    }
```

Comment: If I make "let currentTarget={e};" into an object, I can't dig deeper into it and get values I actually need, and getting class name then looking for that class is not an option because it would give me the first one then I need one I clicked on and there are up to 8 with same class name

Comment: Sorry This was a mistake from my side curly braces need to wrap e.currentTarget rather than e

Comment: Now checkout your answer